# Finding the idNumber element from this below HTML code

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
<div id="rightContent" style="display: inline-block; width: 700px; vertical-align: top;">
                <div>
                    <h1><em class="SomethingHeading">Something</em></h1>
                </div>

<div class="content scaffold-list" role="main">
    <h1>Search</h1>



    <form action="/SomethingArchiveUI/search/search" method="post">
        <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>ID/Registration Number:</td>
                <td>
                    <**input type="text" name="idNumber" maxlength="20" value="" id="idNumber"**>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Client Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="clientName" maxlength="50" value="" id="clientName">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Client Surname:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="clientSurname" maxlength="50" value="" id="clientSurname">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_dateRange"><input type="checkbox" name="dateRange" value="true" id="dateRange"><label for="dateRange">&nbsp;Use date range?</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><p>From: <input type="text" name="fromDate" value="" maxlength="10" id="fromDate" class="hasDatepicker"> To: <input type="text" name="toDate" value="" maxlength="10" id="toDate" class="hasDatepicker"></p></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div style="display: inline;">
            <div id="divSubmit">
                <input type="submit" name="cmdSearch" class="buttons" value="Search" id="cmdSearch">
            </div>
            <div id="divBusy" style="display: none;">
                Busy Searching...
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <table id="customerIdentificationList" style="display: block;">


    </table>
    <div id="loadingMessage" style="display: none;">
        Loading. Please wait.
    </div>
</div>


            </div>
```

I used this code below for logging into the Application, but similar code doesn't seem to work on this form above. I'm trying to find the 'idNumber' element:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='idnumber']")).sendKeys("Username");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'password\']")).sendKeys("Password");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'submit\']")).click();
```

The error i get is: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":

Looking forward to your responses.

Comment: Why are there `*` in the `idNumber` element? --> `<**input ... id="idNumber"**>`

Comment: Lino, the * i just put there to highlight

Comment: I'm guessing that it's just a typo? `idnumber` should be `idNumber`

Answer (score 0):

Use  : .//input[@id='idnumber']

Comment: is that an xpath ?

Comment: I did try it, with no luck unfortunately

Comment: <tr>
                <td>Client Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="clientName" maxlength="50" value="" id="clientName">
                </td>
            </tr> Haveyou got this xpath?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `By.id()`?

```
driver.findElement(By.id("idNumber"));
```

Comment: @Tsietsi and you are sure that there's no Typo?

Comment: @Tsietsi you're code is looking for `idnumber` and the element is defined as `idNumber`

Comment: Lino, I am certain there is no typo. the code with "idnumber" is a different element for a login function. the other "idNumber"(which i am trying to find) is for a different form

Comment: @Tsietsi then why are you providing that code anyway? It's just confusing

Comment: Lino, sorry for the confusion. I thought providing that part of the code will assist me in contextualizing my question, as it works on one form, but fails on another

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason why you can't use By.id() or By.xpath in this case. But you can try to find the input using text in previous td. I hope next code will help:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='ID/Registration Number:']/following-sibling::td/input")).sendKeys("Username");
```

Comment: I noticed that some of your code has escaped quotes like here: "//*[@id=\'password\']". Can it be the case?

Comment: that part of the code works perfectly. it's actually a different form

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below way -

First get the root element and keep it to a WebElement object. Then find for input element idNumber

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#rightContent > div.content.scaffold-list > form"));   
elem.findElement(By.id("idNumber")).sendKeys("Username");
```

Comment: Still getting > org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#rightContent > div.content.scaffold-list > form"}

Comment: @Tsietsi did you use css selector like **By.cssSelector("input[type='text']")** instead of **By.id("idNumber")** in the above solution? The solution may need some modification in that case. Should I do that?

Comment: @Tsietsi did you get your solution?

Comment: please go ahead. I have been trying all suggested solution exactly as they are